# yq error while adding into yaml file from command prompt

Tags: yaml, yq

I am using the following command to add in yaml file by following this [link](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v2.x/write-update).

```
yq w sample.yaml b.c cat
```

I keep getting this error. How do I correct this

```
    Error: Error reading document at index 0, yaml: line 12: could not find expected ':': yaml: line 12: could not find expected ':'
Usage:
  yq write [yaml_file] [path_expression] [value] [flags]
```

Comment: This is an error in your YAML file so you need to show us the content of that file. Also mind that you linked to the `v2.x` docs when current version is `v4.x`, consider updating.

Comment: Yes, I was able to make it work. I was using the command format of v2. Once I used commands of v4, it was able to write the environment variable. I used the following command `sudo yq eval '.services.samson.environment.GITHUB_TOKEN = "ADD_YOUR_TOKEN' -i docker-compose.yml`